# how to pass the VPC ID to the next task on ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to pass the VPC ID to the subnet task to create the subnet, from command line it works and it gives me the ID only:

```
aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
vpc-0b3697513d5914abc
```

but when I execute it in playbook, I also use the debug and it takes whole output:
my script for subnet looks like:

```
# TO DISPLAY VPC ID BELOW:
  - name: TO DISPLAY VPC_ID
    command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
    register: VPC_ID
 #- name:  GREP VPC ID
 #  shell: grep vpc.id "VPC_ID"
  - debug: var=VPC_ID
```

then the output shows me:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "VPC_ID": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "aws",
            "ec2",
            "describe-vpcs",
            "--filter",
            "Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC",
            "--query",
            "Vpcs[].VpcId",
            "--output",
            "text"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:03.275744",
        "end": "2019-12-17 13:57:51.062623",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-12-17 13:57:47.786879",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "vpc-0b3697513d5914abc",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "vpc-0b3697513d5914abc"
        ]
    }
}
```

how I can get in the output only: `vpc-0b3697513d5914abc` ?

Thanks.
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `VPC_ID` is a dictionary (or hash) containing all relevant information to the task that registered it. To access the output only, you can use this:

```
  - name: TO DISPLAY VPC_ID
    command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
    register: VPC_ID

  - debug: var=VPC_ID.stdout
```

Note that `var=VPC_ID["stdout"]` will also work. It mainly depends on your preference, but this notation can be useful in certain scenarios.

I also suggest you have a read of the Ansible documentation on using variables: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html - it'll be hugely helpful if you continue down the Ansible path

Comment: Can you please share your attempt (both the debug task and the output)? Given the output of `VPC_ID` in your original question there is no way this would not work. I think there may be some other issue

Comment: inside my playbook I have:

Comment: # TO DISPLAY VPC ID BELOW:
   - name: TO DISPLAY VPC ID
     command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
     register: vpc
     #command: echo $VPC_ID
   - name: Set VPC ID in Variable
     set_fact:
       vpc_id: "{{ vpc.stdout }}"
   - debug: var=vpc_id

Comment: the output:         TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "vpc_id": "vpc-0a191fbcf360098e3"
}

Comment: From you output it appears that it did work - I see nothing but the ID

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `set_fact` to store the output in a variable and use it in other Ansible tasks.

Below is the snippet which should work for you, It store the value in `vpc_id` variable.

```
- name: TO DISPLAY VPC_ID
  command: aws ec2 describe-vpcs --filter Name=tag:Name,Values= ANSIBLE_VPC --query Vpcs[].VpcId --output text
  register: vpc

- name: Set VPC ID in variable
  set_fact:
    vpc_id:  "{{ vpc.stdout }}"

- debug: var=vpc_id
```